# Importing TypeScript modules using shortcuts in Vue.js application doens't work

Tags: typescript, vue.js, import, module

When I simply create ts file and include it, dev server shows me that the module is not installed. I have:

```
"include": [                                                                                                                  
  "src/**/*.ts"
]
```

in my `tsconfig.json`.

`.vue` files with `<script lang="ts">` section work fine.

I've found that if I import modules like this:

```
import {is_provider_visible} from "../modules/providers";
```

everything works.

But if I import modules like this:

```
import {is_provider_visible} from "@/modules/providers";
```

it doesn't work despite I have:

```
"compilerOptions": {                                                                                                            
  "paths": {
    "@/*": [                                                                                                                  
        "src/*"                                                                                                                 
    ],                                                                                                                        
    "@/modules/*": [                                                                                                          
         "src/modules/*"                                                                                                      
    ]
  }
}
```

in my `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Where in `tsconfig.json` do you have `"paths"`?

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: Hmm. That config should work. Do you have a GitHub link?

Comment: Nope, it's my private project. OK, it's not a big deal to use `..` instead of `@`.